# Achieving a slice-esque page through Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having trouble working with Twitter bootstrap 3 to render a web page composed of different slices. The end-product would be a page composed of `rows` containing `img-responsive` slices that stay in their respective rows (i.e. They don't wrap)

But Bootstrap CSS does something funny with the images. They're nested in the predictable structure, `container>row>col-xs-12>Images`, but even when I set the image `margin: 0;`, there's still a small gap between adjacent images. Moreover, I can't get the `rows` with multiple slices to stay on the same row no matter what (because the page makes no sense if slices wrapped to a new line) and still be "responsive."

Alternatively, if someone could instruct me how to set up a responsive image map (or shoot me a solid link), I could try that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put each image in its own `col-xs-*`, override `col-xs` padding, and add `max-width:100%` to the img. Also, don't get confused by `.row`'s usage. It's not meant to restrict items to a visual row, and doesn't. Frankly, the name is misleading. Just use the single `.row` within the `.container`, and make sure your `col-xs`'s add up to 12 and you'll avoid unwanted wrapping.

**Here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/aYOdYaV4Gq**

```
.col-xs-3{
padding-right:0px;
padding-left:0px;
}

.img{
max-width:100%;
}
```

In my bootply, I've actually *added* classes with these attributes rather than overwriting the bootstrap classes like above. Either works, but adding custom classes means it's easier to turn it on and off later.